# jQuery POST creating a "Method Not Found" error

Tags: jquery, flask

I am creating a Flask application.  I am using Flask version 3.0.2.  I am developing on my work desktop, so the URLs mentioned below are all "`http://127.0.0.1:5000/...`"

I have a MethodView to handle [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations on a database model.  In that view I have a [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) method for adding new database records.  This method is called from JavaScript (rendered from TypeScript) in response to an HTML form submission.  The JavaScript captures the submission in order to send the POST and do page data refreshes without page reload.

I am seeing a, for me, unique interaction after the JavaScript code sends the POST.  The somewhat trimmed JavaScript code is below:

Note: when this runs the page displayed is: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin`. The `url` target of the POST is `http://127.0.0.1:5000/session/<value in reg_id>`

```
let url = $(event.target).attr('data-next');
let reg_id = $(event.target).attr('data-reg_id');

let form_data = get_data_from_form($(event.target))

$.ajax({
    'method': "POST",
    'url': url,
    'data': form_data,
    'beforeSend': (xhr) => {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrf_token);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    }
}).done((data) => {
    this.display_sessions(data);
}).fail((jqXHR) => {
    console.log('add_session fail');
    if (jqXHR.hasOwnProperty('status')) {
        console.log(`add_session fail with status: ${jqXHR['status']}`);
        if (jqXHR['status'] === 412) {
            //
            // Flask is not displaying the form errors so I will.
            this.display_session_form_errors(jqXHR['responseJSON']);
        }
        else {
            // print the error
        }
    }
    else {
        // print the error
    }
})
```

The Flask POST method is below:

```
def post(self, reg_id: str = None):
    try:
        if not self.check_uuid(reg_id):
            raise AttributeError('Invalid registration ID.')

        session_form = SessionForm()

        if session_form.validate():
            session = Session()

            session_form.populate_obj(session)

            db.add(session)
            db.commit()

            # POST
            payload = jsonify(
                {
                    'reg_id': reg_id,
                    'data': self.get_sessions(reg_id, None),
                    'next_url': url_for('session', _method='GET', reg_id=reg_id),
                    'csrf_token': g.get('csrf_token')
                }
            )
            payload.status = HTTPStatus.OK
        else:
            payload = jsonify(
                {
                    'reg_id': reg_id,
                    'errors': session_form.errors,
                    'next_url': url_for('session', _method='GET', reg_id=reg_id),
                    'csrf_token': g.get('csrf_token')
                }
            )
            payload.status = HTTPStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED

        return payload

    except Exception as e:
        current_app.logger.info(f'SessionAPI:post: {repr(e)}')
        return Response(repr(e), status=HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
```

I set the URLs for the MethodView in a static method:

```
@staticmethod
def setup_urls(app: Flask) -> None:
    app.add_url_rule(
        f'/session/<string:reg_id>',
        endpoint='session',
        view_func=SessionAPI.as_view('POST_admin_session_reg_id'),
        methods=['GET', 'POST']
    )
    app.add_url_rule(
        f'/session/<string:reg_id>/<string:session_id>',
        endpoint='session:reg_id:session_id',
        view_func=SessionAPI.as_view('OTHER_admin_session_reg_id_session_id'),
        methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'APPROVE']
    )
```

I bring up the application page with the form to add an item.  I click the submit button and the browser displays a "Method Not Allowed" error.  If I refresh the page with the form I can see that the Flask method successfully handled the request, because the newly entered record is displayed there.

I start debugging and put breakpoints on the JavaScript `$.ajax({` line and the very first line in the Flask `post()` method.  I bring up the the form page, hit submit and the browser debugger stops on the `ajax` call.  I "continue" the browser debug session and the request is created and sent.

[PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) breaks on the first line of the Flask `post()` method and the browser screen is already showing the "Method Not Allowed" screen.  This seems to suggest that the issue is not the `post()` method.

I look at the browser debugger's "Network" tab and see the "Method Not Allowed" error.  I expand the item:

```
General:
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin
    Request Method: POST
    Status Code:    405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
    Remote Address:    127.0.0.1:5000
    Referrer Policy:    strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers:
    HTTP/1.1 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
    Server: Werkzeug/3.0.1 Python/3.11.6
    Date: Tue, 26 Mar 2024 16:31:44 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Allow: HEAD, OPTIONS, GET
    Content-Length: 153
    Vary: Cookie
    Connection: close

Request Headers:
    POST /admin HTTP/1.1
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
    Accept-Language: en-US,en
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 259
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Cookie: ...removed...
    Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
    Origin: http://127.0.0.1:5000
    Pragma: no-cache
    Referer: http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
    Sec-GPC: 1
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
    sec-ch-ua: "Brave";v="123", "Not:A-Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="123"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

I have not seen this behavior before.  I am not sure where to go from here.

Ideas are welcome.

Please note that this is about MethodViews, not regular views.  I am specifying methods via the static method I included above.  The static method is called during application creation.  I can see the routing rules and methods in the application.

Comment: Where is your `@app.route()` in the Flask code?

Comment: They are in the static method listed above. It is called during app creation.  I can see the  resulting route rules and methods in the app metadata.  Plus, the post method is actually running.  Something is causing the Method not allowed write before the post method runs